# Using video as background in a flex box(multiple section required video background)

Tags: html, css, flexbox, html5-video

I have a div with four flex sections.

Two of the four sections need to use video as bg.

But the video looks like don't allow the use of 100% height of the parent.

That's all.

I have googled a lot.

It looks like the video doesn't respect the height/width of the parent, only the video height/width.

## Expected:

All selections are the same size and need a video background for two.

> https://jsfiddle.net/kgpfnq46/
>
> ```css
> body {
>   margin: 0;
> }
>
> #a {
>   display: flex;
>   flex-direction: column;
>   width: 100vw;
>   height: 100vh;
>   background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
> }
>
> #a div {
>   flex: 1;
> }
>
> #a div span{
> font-size: 50px;
> color: white;
> }
>
> #a div video {
>   height: 100%;
>   width: 100%;
>   object-fit: cover;
>   position: absolute;
> }
>
> #a div:first-of-type {
>   /* all image are only for tests! */
>   background: url(https://img.freepik.com/free-vector/hand-painted-watercolor-pastel-sky-background_23-2148902771.jpg?w=2000);
> }
>
> #a div:nth-of-type(2) {
>   background: url(https://img.freepik.com/free-vector/hand-painted-background-violet-orange-colours_23-2148427578.jpg?w=2000);
> }
> ```
>
> ```html
> <body>
>   <div id="a">
>     <div>
>       <span>test</span>
>     </div>
>     <div>
>       <span>test</span>
>     </div>
>     <div>
>       <video src="https://www.sample-videos.com/video123/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4"></video>
>       <span>test</span>
>     </div>
>     <div>
>       <video src="https://www.sample-videos.com/video123/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4"></video>
>       <span>test</span>
>     </div>
>   </div>
> </body>
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few fixes:

- your `video` tag is not correct
- you need to add `position:relative` to `div` parent in order to video fit inside the parent using `position:absolute`
- set `z-index:-1` so it will work as background video

Optionally, your `#a`  background (which I changed to `section`), I'm guessing you want to add it to the areas where `video` are to make contrast with test, if so, then remove it and add it to `div::after`

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}

div {
  flex: 1;
  position: relative;
}

div::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
  z-index: -1;
}

span {
  font-size: 50px;
  color: white;
}

video {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}



div:first-of-type {
  /* all image are only for tests! */
  background: url(https://img.freepik.com/free-vector/hand-painted-watercolor-pastel-sky-background_23-2148902771.jpg?w=2000);
}

div:nth-of-type(2) {
  background: url(https://img.freepik.com/free-vector/hand-painted-background-violet-orange-colours_23-2148427578.jpg?w=2000);
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div>
    <span>test</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>test</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <video autoplay loop muted>
        <source
          src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ElephantsDream.mp4"
        />
      </video>
    <span>test</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <video autoplay loop muted>
        <source
          src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ForBiggerFun.mp4"
        />
      </video>
    <span>test</span>
  </div>
</section>
```